# Javascript functions not opening modal

Tags: javascript

My javascript code does not open my html modal. The IDs seem to be right so I don't understand where the error is.

```
var logModal = document.getElementById("fel-modal");

var logBtn = document.getElementById("button");

var closeLog = document.getElementsByClassName("closeLog")[0];

logBtn.onclick = function() {
  logModal.style.display = "block";
}

closeLog.onclick = function() {
  logModal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == logModal) {
    logModal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Here is the html content that is supposed to show when clicking the button but it doesnt.

```
<button id="button">Anmäl fel</button>
<div id="fel-modal">
<form class="fel-rapport" action="" method="POST">
  <span class="closeLog">&times;</span>

  <h1>Anmäl fel</h1>
  <select name="type">
<option value="">Välj typ av fel...</option>
<option value="HTML">HTML</option>
<option value="CSS">CSS</option>
<option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<option value="SQL">SQL</option>
</select><br>

<select name="type">
<option value="">Välj hur allvarligt problemt är...</option>
<option value="Akut">Skadligt för systemet</option>
<option value="">klgdfjlgjkdfklj</option>
<option value="CSS">fldijklsdj</option>
</select><br>

<textarea type="text" value="" placeholder="Beskriv problemet..."></textarea><br>

<button type="submit" name="button">Anmäl</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please include the HTML that you're trying your code with?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Nothing is happening when clicking the button.

Comment: Is script tag in the head or before the end of body tag ?

Comment: It was in the head. I tried moving it to the end of the document and everything is working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have given is correct (run the snippet below), check to see if their is some element above your element that could be messing with your event listener

```js
var logModal = document.getElementById("fel-modal");

var logBtn = document.getElementById("button");

var closeLog = document.getElementsByClassName("closeLog")[0];

logBtn.onclick = function() {
  logModal.style.display = "block";
}

closeLog.onclick = function() {
  logModal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == logModal) {
    logModal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Anmäl fel</button>
<div id="fel-modal" style="display:none;">
<form class="fel-rapport" action="" method="POST">
  <span class="closeLog">&times;</span>

  <h1>Anmäl fel</h1>
  <select name="type">
<option value="">Välj typ av fel...</option>
<option value="HTML">HTML</option>
<option value="CSS">CSS</option>
<option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<option value="SQL">SQL</option>
</select><br>

<select name="type">
<option value="">Välj hur allvarligt problemt är...</option>
<option value="Akut">Skadligt för systemet</option>
<option value="">klgdfjlgjkdfklj</option>
<option value="CSS">fldijklsdj</option>
</select><br>

<textarea type="text" value="" placeholder="Beskriv problemet..."></textarea><br>

<button type="submit" name="button">Anmäl</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no code above or below the script I have given you. The javascript file is also corectly linked.

Comment: So your entire html file holds only this html code above? Is that right? No `<html></html>` tags? Or `<body></body>` tags?

Comment: Thank you for the help. the link to the javascript was above everything in the html document. After moving it down everything is working.

Comment: Nice! In case you need to know why [here's a link](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-always-put-my-JavaScript-file-in-the-head-tag-of-my-HTML-file-so-that-the-code-is-loaded-at-the-start).

Comment: Btw, please accept the answer so that people know it was the right one, I'll update it with your comment.

Comment: Im sorry im new here, this is my first post. How do I accept an answer

Comment: It's all good. There should be a tick under the two arrows to the left of my question. Do you see it? Under the upvote and downvote buttons